# Highchart, How to export along with sub-topics Highcgarts Drilldown

Tags: highcharts

I have problem, when I export PDF or PNG file. It doesn't show the sub topic. I want to show sub topic when I click drilldown this link demo [`Link Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/teeraphongsing/grL3n9bw/3/) and this when I export [`Picture when export`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO3vP.png) But I want to export like this [`Picture export I want`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5JLr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update subtitle text for exporting, based on generated breadcrumbs.
For example:

```
   chart: {
     ...,
     events: {
       redraw() {
         const breadcrumbs = this.breadcrumbs;
         breadcrumbsText = '';

         if (breadcrumbs) {
           breadcrumbs.list.forEach(list => {
             if (breadcrumbsText) {
               breadcrumbsText += ' / '
             }
             breadcrumbsText += list.levelOptions.name;
           });
         }
       },
       load() {
         if (this.renderer.forExport) {
           this.setSubtitle({
             text: breadcrumbsText
           });
           Highcharts.drawTable(this);
         }
       }
     },
   }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ety8oak4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSubtitle